# GWT 2.5 Application Deployment in Tomcat?

Tags: gwt, tomcat, deployment, gwt-rpc

I am using GWT 2.5. I have an application using gwt-rpc. I have compiled the project and make war file using an ant-script. When I would deploy the project on tomcat it loads successfully but Doesn't show any control. Just a simple blank html page. here are my files.
Module

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  When updating your version of GWT, you should also update this DTD reference,
  so that your app can take advantage of the latest GWT module capabilities.
-->
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.0//EN"
  "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='interviewscheduler'>
  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

  <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
  <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
  <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

  <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->
  <inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwt"/>
  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
  <entry-point class='interviewscheduler.client.InterViewScheduler'/>

  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

</module>
```

Remote Service

```java
package interviewscheduler.client;

import interviewscheduler.shared.Interview;
import interviewscheduler.shared.Teacher;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("interviewScheduler")
public interface InterviewSchedulerService extends RemoteService{
    Boolean loadStudentData() throws IllegalArgumentException;
    Boolean loadParentData() throws IllegalArgumentException;
    Boolean loadTeacherData() throws IllegalArgumentException;
    Boolean loadClassData() throws IllegalArgumentException;
    Boolean loadClassMemberShipData() throws IllegalArgumentException;
    Boolean loadRoomData() throws IllegalArgumentException;
    Boolean loadSessionData() throws IllegalArgumentException;
    Boolean loadInterviewData() throws IllegalArgumentException;
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> getStudentNames() throws IllegalArgumentException;
    String getParentName(String studentKey) throws IllegalArgumentException;
    List<Teacher> getAvailableTeachers(String studentKey) throws IllegalArgumentException;
    List<Teacher> getRequestedTeachers(String studentKey) throws IllegalArgumentException;
    List<Interview> getInterviewByStudent(String studentKey) throws IllegalArgumentException;
    List<Interview> getInterviewByTeacher(String teacherCode) throws IllegalArgumentException;
    List<Object> getInterviewsForGrid(List<Interview> list) throws IllegalArgumentException;
    String addInterview(Interview obj) throws IllegalArgumentException;
    String removeInterview(String studentId, String teacherId) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

Web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

  <!-- Servlets -->

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>interviewSchedulerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>interviewscheduler.server.InterviewSchedulerServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>interviewSchedulerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/interviewscheduler/interviewScheduler</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <!-- Default page to serve -->

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>InterViewScheduler.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong.? Its urgent.

```java
package interviewscheduler.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootLayoutPanel;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.layout.VLayout;

/**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
 */
public class InterViewScheduler implements EntryPoint {
    /**
     * This is the entry point method.
     */
    private InterviewSchedulerServiceAsync remoteObject=GWT.create(InterviewSchedulerService.class);
    private VLayout wrapper=new VLayout();
    private VLayout headerArea=new Header();
    private VLayout contentArea=new ContentArea();

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        Window.enableScrolling(true);
        Window.setMargin("0px");
        remoteObject.loadStudentData(new AsyncCallback<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Boolean result) {

            RootLayoutPanel.get().add(drawWrapper());
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                System.out.println("Failed*****************");
            }
        });


    }

    /** 
     * initialize the wrapper of the web site which holds all other content------Main Container 
     */

    public VLayout drawWrapper(){
        wrapper.setWidth100();
        wrapper.setHeight100();
        wrapper.setMargin(0);
        wrapper.addMember(drawHeaderArea());
        wrapper.addMember(drawContentArea());
        return wrapper;
    }
    /** 
     * initialize the Header Area of the web site which contains Logo with Title and a logout button
     */
    public VLayout drawHeaderArea(){
        headerArea.redraw();
        return headerArea;
    }

    /** 
     * initialize the Content Area of the web site which holds a main TabSet
     */

    public VLayout drawContentArea(){
        contentArea.redraw();
        return contentArea;
    }

}
```

Comment: What does `InterViewScheduler` look like?

Comment: I access the application with this url "http://localhost:8089/InterViewScheduler/" and page looks blank.

Comment: some errors appear on Javascript console. e.g

Comment: [22:46:37.071] Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:8089/InterViewScheduler/interviewscheduler/sc/skins/Enterprise/skin_styles.css:3045

Comment: [22:46:37.071] Expected color but found 'right'.  Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:8089/InterViewScheduler/interviewscheduler/sc/skins/Enterprise/skin_styles.css:3049

Comment: I have noticed that these are only the css errors ...not java script

Comment: @user2065446 I meant what does `InterViewScheduler.java` look like? Can you post it?

Comment: I have posted the code..it loads data via rpc calls to server from a .csv file on server startup.

Comment: You're not doing anything in your app. All you're doing is calling all of these remote services one after the other. You'll never see anything. `System.out.println()` will not show up anywhere if it's done client side. What are you trying to do with the app?

Comment: Have you noticed the last method? drawWrapper() that I have added in rootpanel. It call other classes to draw which I haven't posted. This apps works fine in development mode while running with eclipse. With the embedded server of Google Eclipse Plugin.(Jetty). It works great there.

Comment: What is it that you expect to see?

Answer (score 0):

You have to show your data somehow in your application. All you're doing right now is calling a bunch of services. It's actually quite confusing. You should just do all of that in one call to the server. It will save you A LOT of round trips and most likely will save you from having some failed calls.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't seem to understand what it is you're trying to do. You're making all these RPC calls for which you don't use any of the return values. Regardless of the "useless" RPC calls, you should have `RootPanel.get().add(drawWrapper)` run if the first RPC call succeeds, but I don't know what it will show because with the code that I can see, it will be blank (unless of course there's some CSS or something else that's not shown here).

Comment: Enrybo, Thanks for the help. I have Written all GUI code in two classes. Content and Header. I initialize both of them in InterviewScheduler.java call them in drawHeader and drawContent respectively and the add them to the root panel with the help of drawWrapper method. All of it is working fine in Development mode. While working with eclipse. Is there any reason that it shouldn't work in tomcat if its working fine in jetty (embedded server comes with google eclipse plugin)?

Comment: A mistake I've seen before is not setting up the Tomcat web-app properly. Make sure to Compile your project, copy the war file into the `webapps` and change the `war` name to whatever you want to type in the URL. Don't forget to add your imported libraries to `war/WEB-INF/lib`. I think you did all that right but you never know. Only other thing I can think of is to debug a bit. Try putting a `Window.alert('FOO');` in the `onSuccess()` method and a `Window.alert(caught);` in `onFailure()` to see what's actually happening. I think your service call is failing for some reason.

Comment: The debugging technique worked ...my service call failing due to some reason...here is the message "500 The call failed on the server; see server log for details"

Comment: http://blog.elitecoderz.net/gwt-and-tomcat-create-war-using-eclipse-to-deploy-war-on-tomcat/2009/12/ . Please visit the link...This is the way I am building the .war file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake... I am not including the necessary libraries in WEB-INF/lib directory. Which causes to fail my RPC call. Any ways. Special thanks to Enrybo. Debugging Technique is very useful.